# C#/WPF: Place Popup Control in Center of Screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

Does anyone know how I can place a Popup Control in the Center of the screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the Placement and PlacementTarget properties to position it relative to whatever panel is at the root of the window.  So if I have a `Grid`, `StackPanel`, etc. that contains all the other "stuff" in the window called `MainPanel`, I do something like:

```
<Popup
    PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MainPanel}"
    Placement="Center"
>
```

Comment: question was for centre of screen, not centre of panel or window.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This will place the popup's top left corner in the middle of the screen, it wont center the popup

Answer (score 3):

First, you can use the static properties `FullPrimaryScreenHeight`, `FullPrimaryScreenWidth` of the `System.Windows.SystemParameters` class to get the height and width of the screen.  Then, you can set the `Top` and `Left` properties of your Popup Control using the width and height before showing it.

Something like.

```
double primScreenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight;
double primScreenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth;
_yourControl.Top = (primScreenHeight - _yourControl.Height) / 2;
_yourControl.Left = (primScreenWidth - _yourControl.Width) / 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

None of these answers worked for me in part because I don't have the size of the Popup. I ended up doing this in code behind as follows:

```
var popup = new Popup
{
    Child = new YourUIControlHere(),
    Placement = PlacementMode.Center,
    PlacementRectangle = new Rect(new Size(
        SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth, 
        SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight))
};
```

This could easily be extended to XAML by adding a binding for the screen size.

An obvious enhancement is to use the current screen for multi-monitor support. Getting the current window dimensions is considerably more work however.

Answer (score 2):

Use Grid as container and Alignment will work fine for you:

```
<Popup IsOpen="True">
  <Grid Name="canvasMain">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
      ...
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. This looks like it centers the contents of the popup, not the popup itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Placement="Center" and find ancestor Window using RelativeSource and set "PlacementTarget" property as property like this:

```
         <Popup
            Placement="Center"
            PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
            PopupAnimation="Slide">
               <ContentControl Content="{Binding Yourcontent}"/>
         </Popup>
```

And to keep stupid comments refrained: I know this centers the popup in the middle of the parent window (not neccessarily middle of the screen [if the parent window is not centered on the screen, what really is not regular case]) but this shall statisfy in most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

From the code behind, you can write this. It will alwasy center of the parent whenever your parent is:

```
popup.Left = (parent.Left + (parent.Width / 2)) - (popup.Width / 2);

popup.Top = (parent.Top + (parent.Height / 2)) - (popup.Height / 2);
```