# How can i centred a popup on my window in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup

i want to have a centred popup notifications on my window ( Height="400" Width="500"). See the xaml code below. Is it possible to center it only with xaml (without the code behind)?

```
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="TEXT" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontSize="200" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">

        <Popup x:Name="PopupName" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=ToggleButton,Path=IsChecked}" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Absolute" 
            AllowsTransparency="True"  PopupAnimation="None"   Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid Height="400" Width="500">
                <Rectangle Fill="Silver" Opacity="0.5" Panel.ZIndex="1" Height="400" Width="500"/>

                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Panel.ZIndex="2" Height="150" Width="150">
                    <ListBox Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                        <Label Content="Red" Background="Red" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Label Content="Green" Background="Green" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Label Content="Yellow" Background="Yellow" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>

                <ToggleButton Panel.ZIndex="2" Background="Coral" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Name ="Button"  Width="80" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="5,170,5,5" Content="Close" Click="Button_OnClick"/>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
```

Another option was to use Placement ="AbsolutePoint" with Horizon-/Verticaloffset but it seems like a bit weird :D

Any suggestion? Thx ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762113/c-wpf-place-popup-control-in-center-of-screen

Comment: Thanks for the link but it places the popup's top left corner in the middle of the screen, it doesn't center the popup on my window. I would like to make it without a code behind. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should center the `Popup` in the parent window:

```
<Popup ...
    Placement="Center" 
    PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you :)